# Problems with Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, firefox, crash

I updated to Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit yesterday and there are problems everywhere.
Firefox almost never works. It crashes all the time. I also get some system errors.
I can't find anyone else having the same problems. I wonder if it's a hardware thing. I even reinstalled Ubuntu to see if it was an installation issue but the problems remain the same.

Below is some crash data I collected from firefox:

> [bp-adfc4917-0417-44c9-b333-1480b2140802](https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/adfc4917-0417-44c9-b333-1480b2140802)
>
> [bp-a011a839-742d-4656-b476-cd0a42140802](https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/a011a839-742d-4656-b476-cd0a42140802)
>
> [bp-592009e9-8124-42a7-95fe-355202140802](https://crash-stats.mozilla.com/report/index/592009e9-8124-42a7-95fe-355202140802)

Comment: How *exactly* did you update? If it was from a dvd you might need to run another updated on the newly upgraded machine.

Comment: I didn't update exactly. My previous OS was W8.

Comment: Have you run a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` since? You might not be running the most recent `firefox`.

Comment: I run an update but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I too get some system errors. Most of them are due to a bug causing old errors to pop up.

```
$ sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

should fix that. For `Firefox` try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

Comment: None of them worked. I still get the same errors.

Comment: For me just a system restart was enough.